# How to insert values to another database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I import or insert the result of this query to another database?

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_SALES
```

Comment: You would just `insert` or `select` into the table.

Comment: The condition is the database should reside on the same server else you need to create a linked server first.

Answer (score 1):

Use 3 part naming (you should be using 2 part already). In Pseudo terms:

```
INSERT INTO YourDatabase.YourSchema.YourTable ({Column List})
SELECT {ColumnList}
FROM dbo.TBL_SALES; --I assumed your table was on dbo.
```